# Ctrl key inverts the pressed letter instead of invoking the shortcut command

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, dell-precision

I have a Dell Precision 3581 and an external keyboard Logitech K850.

The problem is that, on both the keyboard of the laptop and on the external one, when I click Ctrl + a..z I just get the secondary language letter instead of running the command.

So, for example, when I want to make a command search with Ctrl + r,  I get the Cyrillic "р" instead of a prompt to write a search phrase.

Does anybody knows what can be the problem here?

Comment: 1. What operating system? 2. What keyboard layouts are installed? 3. Does that happen in *all* keyboard layouts? 4. Is the PC using an app such as AutoHotkey that remaps key combos? **Edit the question** to add needed info.